# I am trying to make a data table with pgfplotstable

Tags: overleaf, pgfplotstable

I am trying to make a data table with pgfplotstable and I don't know how to make the first line into a single column. I made the table horizontal and I can't make the first line into a column or add a new line on top. I use these packages

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

And the data set is

```
B   I
0   0
2   7.95
2.8 11.36
3.8 15.21
4.6 18.28
5.5 22.21
5.9 23.31
6.9 27.30
7.9 31.56
8.9 35.55
\end{filecontents}
```

This is the code that works any attempt of my to make the change I want gives me an error. I have tried to search how to make it but I couldn't find anything that works.

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/index/.style={%
    create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
    }
    }
    }
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=index]\loadedtable{grafic_1.dat} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/colnames/.style={
    string type,
    column name={Table data}},
    column type=l,  % specify the align method
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline}, % style the first row
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},   % style the last row
    every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},  % style the last column
    every column/.style={column type/.add={|},
    column name={}
    }
]
\loadedtable
```

Comment: You are looking for something like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZMKi.jpg or this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7JZm.jpg ?

Comment: I am looking for the first line to show only Table data and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first table uses `booktabs`, already loaded. The second, with vertical lines, uses `\arraystretch` from the package `array` to expand the cells vertically.

With the new versions of LaTeX the package `filecontents` is not longer needed.

[image: zz]

In both cases the first line is inserted with   `\multicolumn{11}{c}{Table data}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 
\usepackage{array}% to expand the cells

%\usepackage{filecontents}% not needed anymore

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{grafic_1.dat}
B I
0 0
2 7.95
2.8  11.36
3.8  15.21
4.6  18.28
5.5  22.21
5.9  23.31
6.9  27.30
7.9  31.56
8.9  35.55
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfplotstableset{
        create on use/index/.style={%
            create col/assign/.code={%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
            }
        }
    }
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=index]\loadedtable{grafic_1.dat}
    
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={%
        before row={\toprule%
        \multicolumn{11}{c}{Table data}
        \\ \midrule},
output empty row},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
string type,
]{\loadedtable} 

\vspace*{60pt}          
    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % expand the cells
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={%
                        before row={\hline%
                        \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Table data}
                        \\ },
                        output empty row},
after row={\hline},
every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}},
string type,
]{\loadedtable}
    
\end{document}
```